# What does Updatepanel response text mean?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, responsetext

When I look at the response text of an updatePanel ajax response in Firebug I see the following code at the top.

```
1|#||4|346045|updatePanel|cphContent_ucProtectContentEditList_upList|
```

It looks like there are 8 items separated by a "|". [Based on this post](http://clementscode.blogspot.com/2011/01/updatepanels-response-text.html) I have deduced that the 5th, 6th, and 7th items are content length, control type, and control id respectively. The 8th position, not shown, is the response body.

What do the first 4 mean?

Answer (score 0):

Basically updatePanel response contains from the following node values where '|' is used as separator: 
ContentLength|ControlType|ControlId|Content

The response is constructed from repeated (ContentLength|ControlType|ControlId|Content) items.

In reality controltype can point not only to update panels or controls but for example have the following values as '#', 'pageRedirect', 'error' and etc.

1|#||4| - specifies version of this response. In this case this response have Version 4. It follows the same principal as (ContentLength|ControlType|ControlId|Content) where

- ContentLength=1,
- ControlType='#' which specifies that this node contains information about version of the response,
- ControlId=EmptyString - version node doesn't have id,
- Content=4 - version value

In any case if you want to know more about all supported values I can advice to review _parseDelta method implementation of the PageRequestManager control which you can found in MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js script.